# Restart a spring batch job

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-batch

I have a spring batch job, that reads from a CSV file and writes into the Database. I want to make it restartable. For example, if there was some exception while reading the file or writing into the db causing the job to fail, it should re-start from the very same point/chunk where it failed and not just read the whole file from the start over.

I'm triggering the job launcher from an endpoint and have configured it in my controller.

Currently I am passing a parameter `jobId`(which is a unique identifier/number) via the controller to the job parameters to run a fresh job instance. In case the job fails, I trigger it again using the same `jobId` as params in the GET request and it restarts the job as expected from where it last failed for that jobId.
The problem with this approach is I have to maintain a separate list of jobId params manually. I don't want to provide a jobId parameter of my own even when I have to run a fresh job instance. Also, this approach fails if I don't pass any value for `jobId` param in the GET request, hence also won't be able to restart that job instance.

I was expecting if there was a way I could just trigger the endpoint without any parameters of my own for every fresh job instance, and in case a job fails I want to restart it by using the `JOB_EXECUTION_ID` or `JOB_INSTANCE_ID` form the spring batch metadata tables.

Controller:

```
@Autowired
JobLauncher jobLauncher;

@Autowired
Job demoJob;

@GetMapping("/demo")
public BatchStatus runDemoJob(@RequestParam(name = "jobId", required = false) String jobId) 
throws JobParametersInvalidException, JobExecutionAlreadyRunningException, JobRestartException, JobInstanceAlreadyCompleteException 
{
        JobParameters p = new JobParameters();

        if (!jobId.isEmpty()) {
            p = new JobParametersBuilder().addString("jobId", jobId).toJobParameters();
        }

        JobExecution j = jobLauncher.run(demoJob, p);

        return j.getStatus();

    }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you use the csv file name as job parameter? If the file name is unique, you will have a job instance per file and you can restart it where it left off in case of failure.

Comment: @MahmoudBenHassine I have to read the same file time and time again because the data in it changes. So using the filename as param won't be a possibility in my case. I need something unique like an ```executionId``` or ```instanceId```

Answer (score 0):

> I have to read the same file time and time again because the data in it changes

Batch processing is about fixed data sets. A single file with a changing content is not a fixed dataset. A streaming solution is probably more appropriate for your use case. A spring batch job instance should represent a fixed data set (identified by identifying job parameters). This is crucial for restartability.

Comment: I meant the contents might change after one execution is complete, and before the next instsnce execution starts. I solved the restartability problem by passing the timestamp as the job parameter instead of a self created jobId.

Comment: That does not mean you solved the restartability problem. With this approach, you can't be sure that restarting a previously failed job instance will process the same data since the file content might have changed in the meantime. Restarting a failed job instance should really replay the exact same data set represented by this job instance (ie exact file, same records in a database table, etc).